Meaning of icons on github notification page
When I go to my "Inbox" (notification centre?) on github, and if I hover my mouse on the right of one of the "messages", I see the following 3 icons. Can someone tell me what they mean?
Moreover, when I click on the "tick" and also the "alarm with a slash", the message disappeared. Is there any way I can get the message back?


You can add it back by going to that specific pull request/issues and click on the subscribe button on the top right side.

What that icon essentially does is it unsubscribed you from a specific pull request/issue. I just figured this out 5 mins ago.
